# Testing class that extends abstract class

Tags: testing, junit, abstract-class

I need to write a test for a class that extends an abstract class. Problem starts when I need to test a method that has `super` reference. So the code looks something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
    public String someMethod();
}

public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    methodToTest(){
        //somecode
        super.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Any idea how should I get around it?

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I am still new to unit testing and just a moment ago figured out why exactly this is not working as I would like to. MyClass in the example above actually contains a initialization block that sets some fields declared in AbstractClass that are used by someMethod so `new AbstractClass.someMethod()` didn't give me the same results as `super.someMethod`. And, as I cannot initialize the AbstractClass it would be impossible to get desired results. I figured that I would need to mock it somehow but as I said I am new to this and have no idea how to do that

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
    String fieldA;
    public String someMethod(){
        //does something with fieldA
    }
} 

public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    {
        setFieldA("something");
    }
    methodToTest(){
        //some code
        super.someMethod();
        //returns some string based on the fieldA value
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** Here is updated version of my code. Please help me with writing test for that. I would probably be able to get it from there:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
    String fieldA;
    public String someMethod(){
        fieldA = "String" + fieldA;
    }
} 

public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    {
        setFieldA("Another String");
    }
    methodToTest(){
        fieldA = fieldA + "Yet Another String";
        super.someMethod();
        return fieldA;
   }
}
```

Comment: No, because you didn't explain what exactly your problem is. Why is it a problem when your class under test calls another method? Why does it matter that this method is actually inherited from an abstract base class? Consider providing a better example, framed around [mcve].

Comment: Edited post a bit. Is it clearer now? I would really appreciate help with this one.

Comment: Well, I find it good enough to answer now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is less about unit testing; but more a general misconception how to work with abstract classes.

First of all: if your abstract class needs a field to do its job, then you better **not** use a setter for that. Instead:

```
public abstract class Base {
  private final String thatField;
  public Base(String incoming) {
    thatField = incoming;
  }
..

public class Derived extends Base {
   public Derived(String incoming) {
     super(incoming);
   }
```

In other words: it seems that this field is an *important* part of your classes. So make that explicit. And by enabling it to be set via constructor, you also ensure that

- you control when/how the field gets set
- you get help from the compiler - by making the field final, you get errors when you forget initializing

Beyond that: when you start testing some class ... it shouldn't matter if that class just extends Object; or if it extends some other class; even when extending an abstract class.

That is about what can be said here; given the fact that your example doesn't contain any specific details about what your code is "really" doing.

Comment: Unfortunately this code is a legacy code that I am not allowed to change unless it actually doesn't work. So refactoring the code to be able to write a test is not an option. So I am going to update my post with a simplified version of my class and would you please help me write a test for this?

Comment: I can arrange that :P