# How to test a function in an abstract class that implements another class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, abstract-class

You can down vote me if you please. I am new to mockito. How do I use mockito to test a function of an abstract class that extends another class.
I trying implementing it below but got a nullPointerException.
I know you are not supposed to use an abstract like this but this is an old code developed by an old team and I need to test my function.
If there is not possibility let me know.

I have seen example in

[Testing class that extends abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781026/testing-class-that-extends-abstract-class)

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements SomeInterface  {

    protected final WebServiceClient webServiceClient;

    protected final AnotherWebServiceClient anotherWebServiceClient;


    public BaseParser(
            WebServiceClient webServiceClient,
           AnotherWebServiceClient anotherWebServiceClient
    ) {
        this.webServiceClient = webServiceClient;
        this.anotherWebServiceClient = anotherWebServiceClient;
    }

 public functionToTest(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg)
    }
```

My Test

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private AbstractClass aClass;

@Test
public void testSave() {
    AbstractClass spy = Mockito.spy(aClass);
    Mockito.doNothing().when((SomeInterface) spy).getId();
    spy.functionToTest(any());
    verify(spy).functionToTest(any());
}
```

Comment: You could ask yourself if it make sense to test an abstract class?

Comment: @D.Lawrence it doesn't make sense I know. But this is how the code was written by an old developer. I am just making a bug fix and I need some help to test if the fix works as intended. You can downvote me as many times as you want but I just need to test this.

Comment: You should maybe start by instantiating a class that extends your abstract class. Then if you want to inject mocks into your class, you need to define them. In that case, you would need two mocks: ```webServiceClient```, ```anotherWebServiceClient```. Try debugging your test to ensure that all your attributes are correctly set. Note also that ```@spy``` is equivalent to ```Mockito.spy(...)```

Comment: @D.Lawrence let me try that

Answer (score 2):

You could write an anonymous implementation of that abstract class in your test case and test that class exposing the method. This way you have a minimal change to your code under test completely in your test code (thus not affecting production code).